# CFG for a^n b^3m c d^m e f^2n with m, n > 0

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I want to find the CFG for this a^n b^3m c d^m e f^2n  with m, n > 0

What I have so far

```
S -> A B C
A -> a A ff
B -> bbb B d
C -> c e
```

Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the grammar:

```
; this rule generates "a" first and "ff" last
S = a A ff

; allow more "a" first and "ff" last
A = S

; between "a^n" and "f^2n" there will be "b^3m c d^m" followed by "e"
A = B e

; this rule generates "bbb" first and "d" last
B = bbb C d

; allow more "bbb" first and "d" last
C = B

; this rules generates "c" between "b^3m" and "d^m"
C = c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar so far allows the `c` to come after the `d` which violates the rules.

The following should work

```
S = a S ff | a bbb B d e ff
B = bbb B d | c
```

The first rule guarantees, that for every `a` in the beginning there are two `f` in the end. It enforces at least one `a`. The second half enforces the sequence `d e ff...`.

The second rule enforces the correct number of `b` and `d` and also that the single `c` is between the `b`s and the `c`s